# Woocommerce Change 'Select Options' button text for specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have the following code that changes the button text of a variable product from 'select options' to select dates.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'change_select_options_button_text', 9999, 2 );
 
function change_select_options_button_text( $label, $product ) {
   if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      return 'Select Dates';
   }
   return $label;
}
```

I'm wanting to apply this only to a certain category instead of it applying to every variable product. Would this be possible?

I've tried adding : `if ( is_product_category('cat1')`

like so but have had no luck.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'change_select_options_button_text', 9999, 2 );
 
function change_select_options_button_text( $label, $product ) {
   if ( is_product_category('cat1') && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      return 'Select Dates';
   }
   return $label;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'change_select_options_button_text', 9999, 2);

function change_select_options_button_text($label, $product) {
    if ($product->is_type('variable') && has_term(array('kids clothing'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id())) {
        // Do something if the product is variable and in category "kids clothing"
        return 'Select Dates';
    }
    return $label;
}
```